# Prove: If $T(u+kv) = T(u) + kT(v)$ then $T$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to prove this statement.

Prove: If $T(u+kv) = T(u) + kT(v)$ then $T$ is linear

It seems to me that for $k=1$ and $u=0$ the statement is proved. Is this correct?

Many proofs use this statement rather than T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v) and T(kv)=kT(v).
It seems intuitive but a proof seems in order. Can it be proved that that 
$T(u+kv) = T(u) + kT(v)$ is always the same as  T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v) and T(kv)=kT(v)?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $T(u+kv) = T(u) + k T(v)$?

Comment: Linearity = additivity + homogenity

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track: all that is left is to write down these two equations, and that is (almost) a proof. BTW, you could try to be more specific in writing your title. Thanks.

Comment: *Is this correct?* Yes.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is linear if

- For all vector pairs $u,v$, the equation $T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v)$ holds.
- For all vectors $v$ and scalars $k$, the equation $T(kv)=kT(v)$ holds.

You must prove these two properties. Just saying $k=1$ and $u=0$ is not a proof, and therefore is not correct. What you must do is take an arbitrary $y$ and $x$ and prove that $T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $T(u+kv)= T(u)+kT(v)$ for all vectors $u,v$ and all scalars $k$.

With the special choice $k=0$, this implies $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ for all $u,v$. With the choice $u=0$ it follows $T(kv)=kT(v)$ for all $k,v$. Hence $T$ is linear.

Often this properties is proved as it slightly reduces the length of the proof. If $T$ is indeed linear, the proof will confirm this, then it is more economically to prove this statement. After all, the proofs for additivity and homogeneity often use the same arguments to obtain the conclusion.